# Remove high linespacing in asciidoctor stem block

Tags: asciidoctor

I am a newbie with asciidoctor trying to use it for education stuff.
I have a `stem` block with linespaces and those linespaces are so huge, that it negativly affect the readability.

**Input**

```
[stem]
++++
=> ggT(120, 7) =   1 * 120 (mod 7)\
=> ggT(120, 7) = -17 *   7 (mod 120)\
               = 103 *   7 (mod 120)\
++++
```

**Output**

[image: Output of the given text over there]

So my Question:

Is it possible to reduce those red highlighted white spaces?
So that these matches the line heigth of the 'normal' text?

Thanks for help!

e.g: Good pages for learning Asciidoctor Syntanx are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the markup around the stem block, so it's hard to say for sure,

I suspect that each stem block is being treated as a paragraph, resulting in the extra whitespace.

Try adding a plus sign (`+`), by itself, on the line immediately before and/or after the stem block, to attach it to the "current" paragraph:

```
+
[stem]
++++
=> ggT(120, 7) =   1 * 120 (mod 7)\
=> ggT(120, 7) = -17 *   7 (mod 120)\
               = 103 *   7 (mod 120)\
++++
+
```

Assuming that I'm correct, you may have to experiment to find the combination that works for your document.